# How to get total length of objects in array correctly

Tags: javascript

Is it even possible to get length of all objects inside an array?
Let say i have an array which looks like that:

```js
var foo = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": {
        "1": [{
            x: 21,
            y: 22
        }, {
            x: 22,
            y: 12
        }],
        "2": [{
            x: 21,
            y: 22
        }, {
            x: 22,
            y: 12
        }]
    }
}];

for (let x in foo) {
    var path = foo[x].path;
    for (let c in path) {
        console.log(path[c]);
    }
}
```

How can i correctly get total lenght of objects inside **path** array here?

Comment: What's your desired output? 4?

Comment: What is the "length" of an object?

Comment: This could mean a lot of different things. Can you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: Well inside "1" array, are some objects, and i want the lenght. The same with "2" array, and get the full length. Wich will be 4 in this case. I can easly hardcode that but, what if i'll add more arrays. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the length of keys:

```
Object.keys(path[c]).length
```

```js
var foo = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": {
        "1": [{
            x: 21,
            y: 22
        }, {
            x: 22,
            y: 12
        }],
        "2": [{
            x: 21,
            y: 22
        }, {
            x: 22,
            y: 12
        }]
    }
}];

for (let x in foo) {
  var path = foo[x].path;
  var totalLen = 0;
  for (let c in path) {
    totalLen += Object.keys(path[c]).length;
  }
  console.log(totalLen);
}
```

Comment: How do i add them together so i will get 4? I can do path[c][0].length + path[c][1].length but i want it to be automatic. So i dont have to do it, everytime i add new array. :)

Comment: @Suttero, you can use one variable.....I have just updated my answer...please check.

Comment: @Suttero, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Added count variable and incremented in the path.

```js
var foo = [{
  "id": 1,
  "path": {
    "1": [{
      x: 21,
      y: 22
    }, {
      x: 22,
      y: 12
    }],
    "2": [{
      x: 21,
      y: 22
    }, {
      x: 22,
      y: 12
    }]
  }
}];
var count = 0;
for (let x in foo) {
  var path = foo[x].path;
  for (let c in path) {
    //console.log(path[c]);
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```